# Is there a way to set a date format to a character when month is numeric?

Tags: sql, vertica

I have 2 columns, say Year:`2010` and Month:`3` and want to create a date from these to columns
I found the following way:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(concat('2010',concat('3','01')), 'YYYYMMDD')
```

It does now work properly as it gives `2012-06-04`, but when I type `'03'` it starts giving the correct answer. How should I change `MM` part in `YYYYMMDD`to make the code working correctly?

Comment: How could that expression possibly give `2012-06-04`?  I'm totally lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might suggest using arithmetic to construct the value, then convert to a string and to a date:

```
select to_date( (year * 10000 + month * 100 + 1)::varchar, 'YYYYMMDD')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also work with `ADD_MONTHS()`, in your case:

```
WITH
indata(yr,mth) AS (
            SELECT 2010,  3
  UNION ALL SELECT 2021,  6
)
SELECT
  ADD_MONTHS('0001-01-01',(yr-1)*12+mth-1) AS resulting_date
, yr
, mth
FROM indata;
-- out  resulting_date |  yr  | mth 
-- out ----------------+------+-----
-- out  2010-03-01     | 2010 |   3
-- out  2021-06-01     | 2021 |   6
```